# React Router DOM - The onClick action updates the URL, but the content does not updates

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm using React and TypeScript to develop an application with multiple pages. I've created a `Pages` folder in the `src` directory, which contains separate folders for `CompanyPage`, `HomePage`, and `SearchPage`. Each of these folders has a corresponding `(foldername).tsx` file and a `(foldername).css` file. In my `App.tsx` file, I've included links to all these files.
However, the issue is that only the URL changes and the content remains the same. Here's the code:

src/Pages/CompanyPage/CompanyPage.tsx

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {}

const CompanyPage = (props: Props) => {
    return <div>CompanyPage</div>;
};

export default CompanyPage;
```

src/Routes/routes.tsx

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../App";
import HomePage from "../Pages/HomePage/HomePage";
import SearchPage from "../Pages/SearchPage/SearchPage";
import CompanyPage from "../Pages/CompanyPage/CompanyPage";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "",
        element: <App />,
        children: [
            { path: "/", element: <HomePage /> },
            { path: "/search", element: <SearchPage /> },
            { path: "/company", element: <CompanyPage /> },
        ]
    }
]);

// Add an empty export statement to make it a module
export {};
```

src/index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'; // Correct import for BrowserRouter

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

src/App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom"; // Make sure to import from 'react-router-dom'
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <Link to="/company">Go to Company Page</Link>
        <br></br>
        <Link to ="/"> App tsx</Link>
        <br></br>
        <Link to="/search"> Search Page</Link>
        <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make
`src/Routes/routes.tsx`: `export default Routers;`

and
`src/indedx.tsx`: `import Routers from './routes';`

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, but maybe also add how `Routers` should be used in `indedx.ts`. Including code snippets which include the original post's code updated to solve the problem could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `RouterProvider` from `react-router-dom` as mentioned in this document: [React Router Dom documentation for createBrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)

your `src/indedx.tsx` should be like this:

```
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { router } from './Routes/routes';
import { RouterProvider as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router router={router}/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```